# Pass parameters via Hyperlink in JSP

Tags: jsp

I have one jsp page called `Allmeters.jsp`, In this page i have `meterid,consumerid` and `consumername` and I  am having hyperlink on `meterid` and this `meterid` value I am passing to another jsp page called `meteridinfo.jsp`.

`Allmeters.jsp` contains the following code from this i am passing meterid value to `meteridinfo.jsp`:

```
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=SNo%></td><td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed">
<a href="meteridinfosuper.jsp?mid=<%=rs.getInt("meterid")%> & consumerid=<%=rs.getInt("Consumerid")%> & consumername=<%=rs.getString("Consumername")%>">
<%=rs.getInt("Meterid")%></a></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getInt("Consumerid")%></td>
<td  bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getString("Consumername")%></td>
<td  align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getInt("LastReading")%></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=checkdate%></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getTime("Time")%></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getString("Status")%></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getString("Subzone")%></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><%=rs.getString("zone")%></td></tr>
```

meteridinfo.jsp contains the following code to display the meterid value that i got from allmeter.jsp:

`<tr><td>
<input type=hidden name="mid" value="<%=request.getParameter("mid")%>">
<label name="name" value="<%=request.getParameter("mid")%>"><font size="4">Meter ID : <%=request.getParameter("mid")%></font></label></td>
</tr>`

here i am able to getting the meterid value in this page but the problem is how to pass the consumerid and consumername to meteridinfo.jsp page only i am having hyperlink value for meterid.Please help me.

Comment: Where rs is defined? Is there content inside the td's?

Comment: in while(rs.next()) only i have this <td> code

Comment: I think it will be better to post **complete** code that contains the broken link, and **complete** code of the page that link to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add one & between the two parameters example :

```
<a href="meteridinfosuper.jsp?mid=<%=rs.getInt("meterid")%>&cid=<%=rs.getInt("consumerid")%>&cname=<%=rs.getInt("consumername")%>">
    <%=rs.getInt("Meterid")%>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply i tried this but it is not displaying

Comment: Does rs.getInt("Meterid") contains something? Can you check the result and see if the <a href=""></a> is printing?

Comment: meterid is dispalying in meteridinfo.jsp  i am using the following code for displaying meterid in meteridridinfo.jsp  <tr><td>
<input type=hidden name="mid" value="<%=request.getParameter("mid")%>">
<label name="name" value="<%=request.getParameter("mid")%>"><font size="4">Meter ID : <%=request.getParameter("mid")%></font></label></td>
</tr> but consumerid and name are not displaying can you please help me because i am very new to jsp.

Comment: It will be easier if you post the complete page here, page that will have the <a href=""></a> inside it. Also tell exactly which parameters and title you want.

Comment: Thank you so much Alexandre problem is solved i used the the above code what you said ,in another page i have added some code like what i did for meterid.Thanks again.

Comment: and now based on this meterid i am getting values from mysql table and i am able store those values in excelsheet but the problem is how to generate excel sheet on client side,can you please help me to solve this.

Comment: You can generate Excel sheets on serverside (example with a Dynamic Document generator Servlet). A good library I use for Excel is http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: i am able to generate the excel in my system but the problem is whenever i am accessing from other system it is storing in mysystem only not in client system.

Comment: Well this is why a good way would be that the web server generates it for you. You can create a Servlet that receive parameters in POST and create a file that you download.

Comment: but my entire project is in jsp how can i write only this file in servlet?

Comment: Start a new question on that, include : a brief example of the content of the excel file (drawing in ASCII) and I'll answer the best I can.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help  i will post the question now

Comment: hi how to fix the selection of radio button usinh jsp

Comment: You'll need to post a new question since we need the context etc.

Comment: hi alexander i have posted my code please help me to solve this

Comment: @Alexander,hi i have a problem with sockets,i have posted my question as client server communication using sockets,can you please help me to solve this.

Comment: Don't comment on answers to get your other questions answered, you need to understand how SO is working...

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="meteridinfosuper.jsp?mid=<%=rs.getInt("meterid")%>
  &consumerid=<%=rs.getInt("consumerid")%>&consumername=<%=rs.getInt(
  "consumername")%>">
```